# Moving objects in PYGAME

Tags: python, oop, object, pygame

I have the code to move 2 objects across my screen. What I want them to do is reach the other side, and restart back at the beginning, however they just cross the screen and disappear.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
winW = 500
winH = 300
surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((winW, winH),0,32)

class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, char, xMoveAmnt, startY=0, startX=0):
        self.char = char
        self.x = startX
        self.y = startY
        self.startX=startX
        self.startY=startY
        self.xMoveAmnt = xMoveAmnt
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.char)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def moveChar(self):
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
        if self.rect.right >= 500:
            self.x=self.startX

enemyList = []
for i in range (0, 2):

    leftOrRight1 = random.randint(0,1)
    if leftOrRight1 == 0:
         leftOrRight = 0
         xMoveAmnt = 20
    elif leftOrRight1 == 1:
        leftOrRight = 500
        xMoveAmnt = -20
    enemyList.append(Enemy(("orc.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 300), leftOrRight))

while True:
    surface.fill ((255,255,255))
    for enemy in enemyList:
        enemy.moveChar()
        surface.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.x, enemy.y))
        time.sleep(00.04)        
    pygame.display.update()
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What determines the position of an `Enemy`? Is it x: `self.x +=...` or is it rect: `if self.rect.right >=...`

Comment: self.x is the x of the object. Increasing it moves the object, the if is meant to move the object back to the starting position when it reaches the far side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
```

Here, you increase the `x` of the `Enemy` to move it.

```
    if self.rect.right >= 500:
```

You were increasing `x` but now you are checking `rect.right`. If you are increasing `x` `rect.right` will not increase. Maybe you meant to do this:

```
    if self.x + self.rect.right >= 500:
```

?

Comment: `rect.right` is a property, it's equivalent to `rect.x + rect.width`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your doing a test on the position of the image's bounding rectangle ( `if self.rect.right >= 500`) while this rectangle is not updated (as you use a 'custom' variable, `x`, for the image's position).

Try doing something like that:

```
def moveChar(self):
    self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
    if self.x >= 500:
        self.x = self.startX
```

You could also use the modulo operator for that kind of things:

```
def moveChar(self):
    self.x = (self.x + self.xMoveAmnt) % 500
```